# how to edit or modify my booleanfield in django

Tags: django

i would be really glad if anyone could help me with my code,i have a model shows if a user is subscribed or not,so i decided to use a boolean field but i want to edit the field so that i can be able to display Subscribed once a client click on it and perform some payment in another url,and the user would be given a specific generated code to use till the subscription is over to access to actions here is what i have written in my model and my output thanks in advance

### models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="patient")
    subscribe = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

### views.py

```
@login_required
def patient(request):
    context = {
        'patient': Patient.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/patient.html', context)
```

### template.html

```
 <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 h4 text-center center">Your Email</legend>
           <legend class=" mb-4 h3 center text-center">{{ user.email }}</legend>
         </fieldset>
         <div class="form-group text-center center">

          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{{ user.patient.subscribe }}</button>
         </div>
      </form>
```

[image: here is the example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tis solve the question

```
  STATE_CHOICES=(
        (True, u'Yes'),
        (False, u'No'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="patient")
    subscribe = models.BooleanField(default=False, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```